# Does the new screen sharing API on Lollipop allow for remote control of the screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-5.0-lollipop

Lollipop includes new API that allows Screen capturing and sharing. Is it possible to use that for remote control of the device screen? Or It just allows screen recording?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Developer Documentations this new feature doesn't allow the remote control. It allows the recording only.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html